# How does `sum` flatten lists?

Tags: python

A multidimensional list like `l=[[1,2],[3,4]]` could be converted to a 1D one by doing `sum(l,[])`. How does this happen?

(This doesn't work directly for higher multidimensional lists, but it can be repeated to handle those cases. For example if A is a 3D-list, then sum(sum(A),[]),[]) will flatten A to a 1D list.)

Comment: This will not transform *any* multidimensional list to 1D. `[[[1,2]], [[3,4]]]` becomes `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

Comment: Also note that it is unsafe to convert just _any_ sequence to 1D, since it is trivial to make sequences with a truly infinite number of dimensions: `a = []; a.append(a)`.

Comment: related "Flattening a shallow list in python" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python

Comment: related "Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`sum` adds a sequence together using the `+` operator. e.g `sum([1,2,3]) == 6`. The 2nd parameter is an optional start value which defaults to 0. e.g. `sum([1,2,3], 10) == 16`.

In your example it does `[] + [1,2] + [3,4]` where `+` on 2 lists concatenates them together. Therefore the result is `[1,2,3,4]`

The empty list is required as the 2nd paramter to `sum` because, as mentioned above, the default is for `sum` to add to 0 (i.e. `0 + [1,2] + [3,4]`) which would result in *unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'*

This is the relevant section of the help for `sum`:

> sum(sequence[, start]) -> value
>
> Returns the sum of a sequence of
>   numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
>   of parameter 'start' (which defaults
>   to 0).

**Note**

As [wallacoloo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216292/wallacoloo) comented this is **not** a general solution for flattening any multi dimensional list. It just works for a list of 1D lists due to the behavior described above.

**Update**

For a way to flatten 1 level of nesting see this recipe from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) page:

```
def flatten(listOfLists):
    "Flatten one level of nesting"
    return chain.from_iterable(listOfLists)
```

To flatten more deeply nested lists (including irregularly nested lists) see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python/2158532#2158532) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) (there are also some other questions linked to from that question itself.)

Note that the recipe returns an `itertools.chain` object (which is iterable) and the other question's answer returns a `generator` object so you need to wrap either of these in a call to `list` if you want the full list rather than iterating over it. e.g. `list(flatten(my_list_of_lists))`.

Comment: Many thanks, understood. May I ask that what is the shortest and best way to flatten a list? At present I can only think of running two nested for loops or a recursive function to do that.

Comment: I've done a quick update to the answer with a recipe for flattening 1 level of nesting and a link to a previous SO question with a more general solution.

Answer (score 56):

If your list `nested` is, as you say, "2D" (meaning that you only want to go one level down, and all 1-level-down items of `nested` are lists), a simple list comprehension:

```
flat = [x for sublist in nested for x in sublist]
```

is the approach I'd recommend -- much more efficient than `sum`ming would be (`sum` is intended for **numbers** -- it was just too much of a bother to somehow make it block all attempts to "sum" non-numbers... I was the original proposer and first implementer of `sum` in the Python standard library, so I guess I should know;-).

If you want to go down "as deep as it takes" (for deeply nested lists), recursion is the simplest way, although by eliminating the recursion you can get higher performance (at the price of higher complication).

[This recipe](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ProblemSets/99%20Prolog%20Problems%20Solutions#Problem_7:_Flatten_a_nested_list_structure) suggests a recursive solution, a recursion elimination, and other approaches 
(all instructive, though none as simple as the one-liner I suggested earlier in this answer).

Comment: Ah I was sure I could do it using list comprehension but was messing up with the code. Thanks and a privilege!

Comment: @alex-martelli, this solution works great but is hard for me to understand.  Would you mind walking me through the order of operations that python follows when executing this solution?

Comment: @NobodyMan, sure, it's just two nested loops: exactly as if within an outer statement `for sublist in nested:` you indented a further statement `for x in sublist:` and then inside it just took the leading expression `x` of the list comprehension to be appended as the next item of the new list you're building. In other words, it works exactly like any other list comprehension with two `for` clauses -- although the leading expression before the `for` clauses is in this case extremely simple:-).

Answer (score 4):

For any kind of multidiamentional array, this code will do flattening to one dimension :

```
def flatten(l):
    try:
        return flatten(l[0]) + (flatten(l[1:]) if len(l) > 1 else []) if type(l) is list else [l]
    except IndexError:
        return []
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me more like you're looking for a final answer of:

```
[3, 7]
```

For that you're best off with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> l=[[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> [x+y for x,y in l]
[3, 7]
```

Comment: No not really, I was trying to find a shorter/better alternative to flatten a 2D list. I am populating a list containing triplets to another list (like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), and I would not enter a number if it is already existing in that list. So my aim is to put something like <num not in [code that flattens a list]>...Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Sayan Then you don't want lists, you want `set`s.

Comment: Hitherto I knew nothing about Python sets. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program to do multi-dimensional flattening using recursion. If anyone has comments on making the program better, you can always see me smiling:

```
def flatten(l):
    lf=[]
    li=[]
    ll=[]
    p=0
    for i in l:
        if type(i).__name__=='list':
           li.append(i)
        else:
           lf.append(i)
    ll=[x for i in li for x in i]
    lf.extend(ll)

    for i in lf:
        if type(i).__name__ =='list':
           #not completely flattened
           flatten(lf)
        else:
           p=p+1
           continue

    if p==len(lf):
       print(lf)
```

Comment: Thank you for offering a suggestion for not relying on a certain amount of dimensions, but when the dimensions exceeded 2, I did not have much success with this ^.  I had to modify to get it to work correctly, by cloning lf to lg, then when recrursively calling flatten: j = flatten(i); lg.remove(i); lg.extend(j)

Answer (score 1):

I've written this function:

```
def make_array_single_dimension(l):
    l2 = []

    for x in l:
        if type(x).__name__ == "list":
            l2 += make_array_single_dimension(x)
        else:
            l2.append(x)

    return l2
```

It works as well!

Answer (score 0):

The + operator concatenates lists and the starting value is [] an empty list.