# python decompose a list

Tags: python, list, operators

I remember I once seen a operator which is able to decompose a list in python.

for example

```
[[1],[2],[3]]
```

by applying that operator, you get

```
[1], [2], [3]
```

what is that operator, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to pass a list of arguments to a function, you can use `*`, the splat operator. Here's how it works:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
function_that_takes_3_arguments(*list)
```

If you want to assign the contents of a list to a variable, you can list unpacking:

```
a, b, c = list # a=1, b=2, c=3
```

Comment: I guess the `*` is the operator in question. It works only in function calls!

Comment: ah, finally, I was trying *, but now know it works only in function calls, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: NB: If the list is shorter than expected params, it will throw eg. ``TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'``, unless the function uses a default value for all parameters. In that case, it fills them in order, and the items beyond list length use the default value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tuple` function to convert a list to a tuple.  A tuple with three elements isn't really any different from three separate elements, but it gives a handy way to work with all three together.

```
li = [[1], [2], [3]]
a, b, c = tuple(li)
print a  # [1]
```

Comment: Adding `tuple` is pretty pointless because `a, b, c = li` works just the same.

Comment: It's pointless in this example but if you don't unpack it straight away, it's not. You can do some things with tuples you can't do with lists: in particular, use them as dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to the OP's question: "what is that operator" which transforms the list `[[1],[2],[3]]` to `[1], [2], [3]` is `tuple()` since `[1], [2], [3]` is a tuple. The builtin function `tuple` will convert any sequence or iterable to a tuple, although there is seldom a need to do so since, as already pointed out, unpacking a list is as easy as unpacking a tuple:

```
a, b, c = [[1],[2],[3]]
```

gives the same result as

```
a, b, c = tuple([[1],[2],[3]])
```

This may not be what the OP wanted but it is the correct answer to the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by running `sum(list_name,[])` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961983/convert-multi-dimensional-list-to-a-1d-list-in-python).

You may also find this question on [flattening shallow lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) relevant.

Comment: From your own link, it does not appear to be `sum(1,list_name)` but rather `sum(list_name, [])`.