# How to assign multiple items in a list to a variables by creating a definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'am trying to create a definition that assigns objects in a list to variables but unfortunately it is not working:

when I try to print `player_1` (as in the last step) it gives me a

```
NameError
```

Any suggestion or feedbacks on how to make  the definition shorter or better is always welcome. The whole project( it is till the beginning) is on https://github.com/ahmadkurdo/project---a

If you have time and look at it and give me some feedback on it would be appreciated.

```
def assign_players(list_of_names):
    if len(list_of_names) == 2:
        player_1 = list_of_names[0]
        player_2 = list_of_names[1]

    elif len(list_of_names) == 3:
        player_1 = list_of_names[0]
        player_2 = list_of_names[1]
        player_3 = list_of_names[2]

    elif len(list_of_names) == 4:
        player_1 = list_of_names[0]
        player_2 = list_of_names[1]
        player_3 = list_of_names[2]
        player_4 = list_of_names[3]

    elif len(list_of_names) == 5:
        player_1 = list_of_names[0]
        player_2 = list_of_names[1]
        player_3 = list_of_names[2]
        player_4 = list_of_names[3]
        player_5 = list_of_names[4]

    elif len(list_of_names) == 6:
        player_1 = list_of_names[0]
        player_2 = list_of_names[1]
        player_3 = list_of_names[2]
        player_4 = list_of_names[3]
        player_5 = list_of_names[4]
        player_6 = list_of_names[5]


number_of_players = int(input('How many players are playing?  '))
list_of_players = []

while number_of_players > 0:
    name_player = input('What is your name  ')
    list_of_players.append(name_player)
    number_of_players = number_of_players - 1

assign_players(list_of_players)

print(player_1)
```

Comment: You already have your items in a list, why want them to pollute your scope?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the **scope of your variables**. ***Scope*** means: where is my variable defined/visible and when is it no longer defined.

If you define a variable inside a function (like you do) it is only known inside this function - you can not access it once you leave the function.

The variable is unknown - hence `NameError`.

You can however `return` it and by assign it to some other variable as return of your function.

You can work around your specific problem (and get rid of those `if` statements) by simplifying your code like this:

```
number_of_players = int(input('How many players are playing?  '))
list_of_players = []

for _ in range(number_of_players):
    list_of_players.append(input('What is your name  '))

player_1,player_2,player_3,player_4,player_5,player_6, *rest = list_of_players + [None]*5

print(list_of_players + [None] * 5) 
print(player_1)
print(player_2)
print(player_3)
print(player_4)
print(player_5)
print(player_6)
print(rest)
```

Output for `2` + `'jim'` + `'bob'`:

```
['jim', 'bob', None, None, None, None, None] # filled up with [None] * 5
jim
bob
None
None
None
None
[]
```

The code works by filling up your list to the needed amount of items (using `[None]` for any not inputted) so that you can decompose the list again into your variables. **BUT** it would be much easier to leave them in a list:

```
for round in range(1,10):
    for player in list_of_players:
        print (player, "'s turn:")
        # do something with this player
```

This is kindof difficult to do if you want to use your `player_X` variables instead and would lead to lots of duplicate code and you still would have to check if your player_X are filled or None ...

Read more about:

- [variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)
- [list decomposing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319612/python-decompose-a-list)

As function:

```
def assign_players(p): 
    return p + [None]*5

p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,*rest = assign_players(list_of_players)
```

Comment: Sir thank you VERY MUCH your help and feedback is appreciated!